# scroll functionality is not working in ipad, can anyone do help on this? using appium

Tags: appium

I am trying to do scroll functionality ipad I tried all the possibility 
ex: ScrollTo("") and ScrollToExtract() and also JavaScript am not able to scroll in ipad but iphone it's working fine

Comment: any one help me in this, am using native app

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
 public void scrollDown() {
            Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
            int x = size.width / 2;
            int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.85);
            int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.10);
            driver.swipe(x, starty, x, endy, 2000);
    }
```